# Connection closed by 127.0.0.1

Tags: hadoop, ssh

i am working here with hadoop framework . i installed hadoop before from this sites : http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/05%20-%20Setup%20SSHD.html. it works before for me. but now i have to install it in another pc. i tried same steps but stucked here

at command :  ssh localhost 
  it shows me error:  connection closed by 127.0.0.1

i tried to googled many times but unable to get it . any body pls help:

i working here with cygwin in windows 7:
error prompt is here :

```
$ ssh localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 37:80:a5:b5:29:29:35:ee:f3:7c:67:28:d0:27:9b:d4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

after using ssh -v localhost :

```
 ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/VINOTHINI/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/VINOTHINI/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/VINOTHINI/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/VINOTHINI/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/VINOTHINI/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/VINOTHINI/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 37:80:a5:b5:29:29:35:ee:f3:7c:67:28:d0:27:9b:d4
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/VINOTHINI/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/VINOTHINI/.ssh/id_rsa
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Try running in verbose mode: `ssh -v localhost` and post output here.

Comment: Edit your question and put it there, it will be much clearer

Comment: @Stefano i tried it not working . it shows many more debugging and at last connection closed by 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yeah exactly. **We need _more debugging info_ to be able to help you**

Comment: @Stefano i have edited my question pls see it there

Comment: Is your public key in the `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: @Stefano Yeah there is ssh-rsa key which is encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at last i got it , it was because of my Avast antivirus. it was blocking the local server to open. I uninstalled it and got running. May it will help someone.

Comment: Yep, Add rule in antivirus program so in future it wont block any port which you are using